# Как получить URL после redirect'а (AsyncHttpClient)

Tags: android, loopj

Делаю запрос с помощью библиотеки http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.setEnableRedirects(false);
client.get("http://httpbin.org/redirect-to?url=ip", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {
        // called when response HTTP status is "200 OK"
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] errorResponse, Throwable e) {
       if (statusCode == 302)
       {
            getRedirectLocation(headers);
       }
    }

});
```

Суть в следующем, если выставляю Allow Redirects = true, я перемещаюсь на конечную страницу, но не могу узнать URL на которой нахожусь.

Сейчас делаю следующим образом:
1. запрещаю redirect
2. в обработчике onFailure проверяю на 302, и в header смотрю location
А хочется получить url куда нас запнули, без лишних телодвижений.

Мб другая какая билиотека может это :-)

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в сторону [retrofit'a](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127626/how-do-you-prevent-retrofit-from-automatically-following-a-302) подробнее рассматривается Ваша проблема